# Documentation of Vuetify 1.3.0

Tags: autocomplete, vuejs2, version, vuetify.js

I use the [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/) 1.3.0 version. The documentation of vuetify based on the version 1.5.11 and 1.0.x. I want to use Autocompletes component, i know this component exist in version 1.3.0, but there is no example for this component, current version example not working. How can I find the documentation for version 1.3.0?

Comment: Hey! it is here,: https://v1.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#example-autocomplete

Comment: hey this site is not working can u please provide a link which is working of vuetify v1.3.x

Comment: https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes - current supported version in v1.5.